# Was there a real person for Cardinal Vitori mentioned in This Side of Paradise of F. Scott Fitzgerald?

Tags: f-scott-fitzgerald, historical-context

> known by name as a fabulously wealthy American girl to **Cardinal Vitori** and **Queen Margherita** and more subtle celebrities that one must have had some culture even to have heard of.

I was able to find Queen Margherita - [Margherita of Savoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margherita_of_Savoy). The same time period as described in the novel.

But for Cardinal Vitori I was only able to google [Loreto Vittori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loreto_Vittori), who was an Italian castrato and composer and not a Cardinal and lived far before 1920s.

Was it a fictional character thought up by F. Scott Fitzgerald?

Answer (score 5):

[This Cambridge edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZslGpJEmE0C&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316&dq=Cardinal%20Vitori&source=bl&ots=rMsNyQ5Q0O&sig=ACfU3U2Nl0vTjDXNIRxjfsxZ08eRxWsqEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5muX3nuHkAhXRQ0EAHRhSAIYQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Cardinal%20Vitori&f=false), with explanatory notes by James L W West III and Lynn Setzer specifically notes that although Margherita di Savoia was a real person, Queen of Italy from 1878 to 1900 and Queen Dowager thereafter, Cardinal Vitori was a fictitious character.

This does not completely rule out his character being in some way based on a real person.  However [James LW West III](http://english.la.psu.edu/faculty-staff/jlw14) is

> Professor of English, Emeritus, at Pennsylvania State University. He is a biographer, book historian, and scholarly editor.

While Lynn Setzer is a former student he credited with much of the historical research, so the notes seem to be a work of some scholarship.